# Myheadings, markboth and page number

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I assume I'm not understanding something about myheadings and markboth. Here is my MWE (I'm running this on MikTeX 2.9 on a Win10 box):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\markboth{}{Why is this not the right number? \arabic{page}}

First page.

\newpage

Another page.

\newpage

And another.

\end{document}
```

In all of the three pages, `\arabic{page}` in the header prints 1, instead of the expected 1,2,3.

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting: the `\rightmark` is set at the moment the `\markboth` command is processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool for setting page numbers. Anyway, using `\protect\thepage` solves the issue, as it avoids `\thepage` being expanded at the moment `\rightmark` is assigned a value and deferring its evaluation to the header's print time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\markboth{}{Why is this not the right number? \protect\thepage}

First page.

\newpage

Another page.

\newpage

And another.

\end{document}
```

[image]